# IS PHP Cron the right one for checking and notifying bidding winner?

Tags: php, apache, job-scheduling

I am being asked by my client for making instant notification to the bid winner when the bid expires.

Since the ending time is varying and set by users while registering bids, I am planning of setting cron jobs to run every 5 mins and check any finished bids without notification and notify all of them.

Do i have another good method to accomplish this task?

Comment: is this your auction site, or a remote one ..?

Comment: a job that runs every 5minutes only wouldn't exactly qualify as "instant".

Comment: @Dragon: yeah its a auction site.

Comment: not what was asked, if its yours wont the auction site already have something for closing completed auctions?

Comment: I am developing the auction site. I haven't set anything for closing complete auctions... Do i have to set corn job while registering auuction

Comment: They are called **cron** jobs, not **corn** jobs.  Well, assuming we are talking about the same thing :)

Comment: Also, why can't you run your corn job with more granularity?  Maybe, every 5 seconds or so?  Create a mutex to keep it from running more than once concurrently.

Comment: @MarcB You are winning a bid and get notified within an average of 2.5 minutes... That's pretty much "instant" in that context. Just because the client says "instant" doesn't mean that he really want (or need) it to happen within nanoseconds of the event. If the client does want it faster, he only needs to change it to 1 minute intervals (notifications sent within 30 seconds on average) and that's that.

Comment: @sberry Minimum is 1 minute. That's plenty fast enough.

Comment: @KoolKabin 1 cron job only. It will run a php script every X minutes.

Comment: hmm... does running it on every second gives consumes a much resource on server? will it give high load to server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into something for queueing tasks.  Me personally... I would use [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/), because I love Python and Celery is freaking awesome.

If you are married to, or have to use PHP, then [beanstalk](http://kr.github.com/beanstalkd/) looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of cron jobs, I prefer it integrate the job listings into my MVC. That way, upon every request it can check to see what jobs need to be preformed. Then I have a cron job call any link to my MVC so that jobs can be completed without the need of a request being sent.

Thats just me, you might be able to find a better alternative to fit your site.